# igCombo template doesn`t effect selected item

Tags: javascript, infragistics, ignite-ui

When I set index in selectedItems properety in order to display preset value in igCombo, provided itemTemplate is not used for generating the text value.

```
$(selector).igCombo({
        dataSource: this.userComboDs,
        width: '300px',
        textKey: 'line1',
        valueKey: 'id',
        mode: 'dropdown',
        enableClearButton: false,
        closeDropDownOnSelect: true,
        itemTemplate: "<span>${city}, ${line1}</span>",
        selectedItems: [
          {
              index: 1 // random index value
          }],
        selectionChanged: function (evt, ui){
        },
        filteringType: "local",
        filterCondition: "contains",
        renderMatchItems: "contains"            
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `itemTemplate` is only applicable to the items in the `igCombo` list. The input field of the `igCombo` is populated with the text key data property of the selected item.